# How can i get the solution of complicated equation?

Tags: equation-solving

[image]

This is the equation about zeta. `NSolve[eq]` could not solve this equation. (I think it is too complex to solve by `NSolve`.)

I want to know how can I solve this equation, which has such a complicated form.

This should be the code for the equation:

```
eq = (0. - 30.1996 I) ζ^6 +
  (0. + 9.81486 I) ζ^5 Sqrt[(0. - 640.701 I) + ζ^2] +
  (0. + 20.3847 I) ζ^4 ((0. - 640.701 I) + ζ^2) +
  (0. + 20.3847 I) ζ^5 Sqrt[(0. - 1127.53 I) + ζ^2] -
  (0. + 20.3847 I) ζ^3 ((0. - 640.701 I) + ζ^2) Sqrt[(0. - 1127.53 I) + ζ^2] +
  (0. + 9.81486 I) ζ^4 ((0. - 1127.53 I) + ζ^2) -
  (0. + 9.81486 I) ζ^3 Sqrt[(0. - 640.701 I) + ζ^2] ((0. - 1127.53 I) + ζ^2) +
  408.549 (
    (0. - 0.630868 I) ζ^3 - (0. + 14.0909 I) ζ^2 Sqrt[(0. - 640.701 I) + ζ^2] -
    (0. + 1.21667 I) ζ ((0. - 640.701 I) + ζ^2) -
    (0. + 6.45738 I) ζ^2 Sqrt[(0. - 1127.53 I) + ζ^2] +
    (0. + 14.7217 I) ((0. - 640.701 I) + ζ^2) Sqrt[(0. - 1127.53 I) + ζ^2] +
    (0. + 0.585806 I) ζ ((0. - 1127.53 I) + ζ^2) +
    (0. + 7.08825 I) Sqrt[(0. - 640.701 I) + ζ^2] ((0. - 1127.53 I) + ζ^2)) == 0;
```

Comment: You can try `FindRoot`; if you post actual code people will be more willing to help though.

Comment: Also it might be helpful to know the context in which the equation came up. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Justed added the code using OCR.

Answer (score 3):

This can be simplified quite a bit, since most of the real parts are zero:

```
f[ζ_] = 
 FullSimplify[(0. - 30.1996 I) ζ^6 + (0. + 9.81486 I) ζ^5*
     Sqrt[ζ^2 - (0. + 640.701 I)] + (0. + 20.3847 I) ζ^5*
     Sqrt[ζ^2 - (0. + 1127.53 I)] + (0. + 
       20.3847 I) ζ^4 (ζ^2 - (0. + 640.701 I)) + (0. + 
       9.81486 I) ζ^4 (ζ^2 - (0. + 1127.53 I)) - (0. + 
       9.81486 I) ζ^3*
     Sqrt[ζ^2 - (0. + 640.701 I)]*(ζ^2 - (0. + 
         1127.53 I)) - (0. + 
       20.3847 I) ζ^3 (ζ^2 - (0. + 640.701 I))*
     Sqrt[ζ^2 - (0. + 1127.53 I)] + 
    408.549 ((0. - 0.630868 I) ζ^3 - (0. + 14.0909 I) ζ^2*
        Sqrt[ζ^2 - (0. + 640.701 I)] - (0. + 
          6.45738 I) ζ^2*
        Sqrt[ζ^2 - (0. + 1127.53 I)] - (0. + 
          1.21667 I) ζ (ζ^2 - (0. + 640.701 I)) + (0. + 
          0.585806 I) ζ (ζ^2 - (0. + 1127.53 I)) + (0. + 
          7.08825 I)*
        Sqrt[ζ^2 - (0. + 640.701 I)] (ζ^2 - (0. + 
            1127.53 I)) + (0. + 
          14.7217 I) (ζ^2 - (0. + 
            640.701 I)) Sqrt[ζ^2 - (0. + 1127.53 I)])]

FindRoot[f[ζ] == 0, {ζ, 7}]

(* {ζ -> 6.98478 + 0.493405 I} *)
```

Where my guess for the root was from a quick look at the plots:

```
Plot[{Re[f[ζ]], Im[f[ζ]]}, {ζ, -10, 10}]
```

[image: plots]

**Edit:** The `Rationalize[]` wasn't necessary

Answer (score 3):

### Introduction

#### Update 6/2014

Originally, I found three solutions; now it's six.  I thought I knew there were three because rationalizing the equation results in a polynomial of degree 24 and `NSolve` finds 24 roots and then eliminate roots that were not zeros of the original equation.  It turns out the equation was troublesome from the point of view of numerics and I missed three.

Other modifications:

- It seems more natural to use `Rationalize` to convert the coefficients to exact numbers in this case than `SetPrecision`.
- Likewise I replaced `First @ eq` with `Subtract @@ eq`.

### Rationalize the equation

One should keep in mind that according to [the documentation on `NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSolve.html)

> `NSolve` deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations.

The OP's equation is an algebraic equation that can be turned into a polynomial equation, which `NSolve` can then solve easily.  Since `NSolve` does not do this on its own, we have to rationalize "by hand."  Rationalization tends to introduce extraneous solutions, so we have to check the answers returned by `NSolve`.  The somewhat nasty coefficients of `eq` make it harder, since in rationalizating `eq`, round-off error leads to some of the square-roots not canceling out as they should.  We can fix that by setting the precision of `eq` to `Infinity`.

We can find the square-roots in an expression `expr` with

```
DeleteDuplicates @ Cases[expr, Power[_, 1/2], Infinity]
```

Then for each square-root, we can multiply `expr` by the expression with the square-root replaced by its negative and simplify.

Below is the result of applying the method to the function obtained by replacing `Equal` in `eq` by `Subtract` with [`Apply` (`@@`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html).  We can solve the equation exactly.

```
eqExact = Rationalize[Subtract @@ eq];

rationalized = 
 Simplify @ Fold[
   Expand[Times @@ (#1 /. {{}, {#2 -> -#2}})] &,
   eqExact, 
   DeleteDuplicates@Cases[eqExact, Power[_, 1/2], Infinity]];

rootsRatExact = Solve[rationalized == 0, ζ];
rootsRat = NSolve[rationalized == 0, ζ]
(* 24 roots
   {{ζ -> -24559.6 + 24559.6 I}, <<22>>, {ζ -> 24559.6 - 24559.7 I}}
*)
```

There are some significant differences between the two solutions:

```
(ζ /. rootsRat) - (ζ /. rootsRatExact) // Abs // Max
(*
  3.15226*10^-10
*)
```

### Selecting the roots of the given equation

**Update**: Here is where I missed some zeros.

I used `Pick` to select roots at which the original equation `eq` has a small value, less than some small threshold, say `10^-1`.  We can check later that each is a root, but I did not check for other roots.  The original roots were:

```
rootsEq = Pick[rootsRat, Abs[Subtract @@ eq] < 10^-1 /. rootsRat]
(*
   {{ζ -> -3.78042 - 5.50655 I}, {ζ -> -3.20562 + 5.39914 I}, {ζ -> 6.98478 + 0.493405 I}}
*)
```

These correspond to roots 7, 9, and 20 in `rootsRat`:

```
Position[Subtract @@ eq /. rootsRat, _?(Abs[#] < 10^-1 &)]
(*
  {{7}, {9}, {20}}
*)
```

If I check the exact equation for zeros with `PossibleZeroQ`, I get more roots:

```
Position[eqExact /. rootsRatExact, _?PossibleZeroQ]
(*
  {{1}, {7}, {9}, {14}, {20}, {21}}
*)
```

[Note: `PossibleZeroQ[.., Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"]` takes forever on these potential roots, or at least longer than I was willing to wait.]

Interestingly, these additional roots are connected to the differences between the results returned by `NSolve` and `Solve`:

```
Position[Abs @ Chop[(ζ /. rootsRat) - (ζ /. rootsRatExact), 10^-13], _?Positive]
(*
  {{1}, {2}, {3}, {14}, {21}, {22}, {23}, {24}}
*)
```

Let's let our new roots be the following and we can check them below:

```
rootsEqNew = Pick[rootsRatExact, PossibleZeroQ[eqExact /. rootsRatExact]];
rootsEqNew // N
(*
  {{ζ -> -24559.6 + 24559.6 I},   {ζ -> -3.78042 - 5.50655 I}, {ζ -> -3.20562 + 5.39914 I},
   {ζ -> -0.0832786 - 722.827 I}, {ζ -> 6.98478 + 0.493405 I}, {ζ -> 722.642 - 0.100823 I}}
*)
```

#### Checks

At first, at doesn't look too good for the new additions:

```
eqExact /. rootsEqNew // N
(* 
  { 0.            + 9.7614*10^12 I,    (*  {1} *)
   -1.49012*10^-8 + 3.91155*10^-8 I,   (*  {7} *)
   -1.39698*10^-8 - 3.63216*10^-8 I,   (*  {9} *)
   -2.            + 1536. I,           (* {14} *)
    1.49012*10^-8 + 1.11759*10^-8 I,   (* {20} *)
    0.            + 1024. I}           (* {21} *)
*)
```

The problem is in evaluating the equation with machine precision.

```
N[eqExact /. rootsEqNew, 50]
(* N::meprec warning about $MaxExtraPrecision being reached *)
(*
  {0``69.62973568978663 + 0``69.69302870899077 I, 
   0``90.5174054423328  + 0``90.55817837498498 I, 
   0``90.50250822096415 + 0``90.54414468499085 I, 
   0``80.1824915073549  + 0``79.76650578675965 I, 
   0``90.47483650216002 + 0``90.49782363232914 I, 
   0``80.17292602755023 + 0``79.76710897249409 I}
*)
```

The warning does not appear to be significant.  Bumping up `$MaxExtraPrecision` to `2000` still produces the warning and zeros with accuracies around `2020` to `2040`.  If they are zeros, `N` probably will always produce the warning, since `0.` cannot have a `Precision` (other than `MachinePrecision`).

Comment: `NSolve[Rationalize[eqs],\[Zeta], WorkingPrecision ->500]` will give results in agreement with your 6. `MachinePrecision` is not sufficient to validate three of the roots.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Oh, of course.  Thanks.

Comment: Wasn't as obvious as one might like, since `NSolve` with defaults was falling flat on this. I found the underlying problems so at some point it will do better (getting all but the last solution, which it discards due to size of residual at relatively modest precision).

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by b.gatessucks, though this seems to produce imperfect results---and I don't understand why Intersection[out,out] does not remove repeated roots...

```
eq2 = FullSimplify[eq == 0];
out = ParallelTable[ ζ /. Quiet@FindRoot[eq2, { ζ, 500 RandomComplex[]}], {5000}];
test = Intersection[out, out];
tol = 10^-1;
list = {test[[1]]};
Do[
  If[Norm[test[[i]] - test[[i + 1]]] > tol, 
   AppendTo[list, test[[i + 1]]]], {i, Length[test] - 1}];
list[[Flatten@
   Position[
    Chop[ eq /. ζ -> list[[#]] & /@ Range[Length[list]], 10^-6], 
    0]]]
```

This is not pretty, nor particularly robust.

Comment: `Intersection[out, out]` doesn't remove repeated roots because they are not exactly the same, only approximately the same.  Use something like `DeleteDuplicates[out, Chop[#1 - #2] == 0 &]`. (You'll find that `FindRoot[eq2, { ζ, 500 RandomComplex[]}]` does a pretty bad job and produces hundreds of non-roots.)